# Get max value for property from a given array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
/**
 * A prototype to create Weekday objects
 */


  function Weekday (name, traffic) {
        this.name = name;
        this.traffic = traffic;
    }
//function to return the day that has the most traffic.
function mostPopularDays(week) {
    // IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION!

}
//this is my input
var a = new Weekday('mon',123); var b = new Weekday('tues', 134) ; var c = new Weekday('wed', 233);
empty_me = []; 
empty_me.push(a ,b ,c);
mostPopularDays(empty_me);
// it should return the day with most traffic
//e.g wed
```

This code is collecting input as an array with objects embedded inside it... the function 'mostPopularDays' should return a string of the name of the day with the most traffic or an array with the names of the days with the most traffic.

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: what is the input? please take valid data and format it correctly.

Comment: Weekday seems to be an object of a class, not a simple object. You might need to know the access methods of this class

Comment: please, I've edited the question, may be you'd understand better now.

Comment: please add the part of `// IMPLEMENT THIS FUNCTION!`.

Comment: @NinaScholz That's what he's asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `reduce` array method to do this:

```
function mostPopularDays(week) {
    let mostTrafficInADay = week.reduce((acc, val) => {
        acc = ( val.traffic > acc ) ? val.traffic : acc;
        return acc;
    }, 0);
    return week.filter(day => day.traffic === mostTrafficInADay).map(day => day.name);
}
```

This will return an array containing strings of all of the names of the days where the traffic was the highest.

Edit: since the question changed, it also uses the array `map` and `filter` methods.

Comment: please check out my edited post

Comment: @StanleyLuke: Just noticed you moved the goalposts, you only want the name of the day with the most traffic. Changed the function to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Please what if we have more than one day with same traffic, can you share a code to return the days as an array. eg [thurs,fri]

Comment: I was going to ask you what you want to happen in this case. I'll do this for you, but just know that constantly changing the goalposts of a question is not good SO etiquette.

Comment: @StanleyLuke it might be worthwhile to give this a read: https://medium.com/jsguru/javascript-functional-programming-map-filter-and-reduce-846ff9ba492d

Comment: @StanleyLuke I just updated the answer as it had a mistake in it - the accumulator of the `reduce` function needs to be 0 to start with.

Comment: @StanleyLuke You changed the question again! Do you really want to output a string when there's only one day, and an array when there's more than one day? That will just make your life harder. Just working with an array, regardless of how many days are in it, will simplify things a lot for you. Otherwise you would need to do extra type checking when working with the value returned from `mostPopularDays()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit long but
first you can find max value then find relevant items in list matching

```js
var wdArr = [ {name: "mon", traffic: 123}, {name: "tue", traffic: 120}, {name: "wed", traffic: 124}, {name: "thurs", traffic: 455}]



resInt = Math.max.apply(Math, wdArr.map(function(o) { return o.traffic; }))

resObj = wdArr.filter (function(el){

return el.traffic == resInt
});

console.log(resObj)
```

Comment: What is the jQuery for? your code has no dependency on jQuery.

Comment: fixed thanks for notification

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the traffic value in the `array#redcue` and get the height valued `traffic` object.

```js
let data = [{name: "mon", traffic: 123}, {name: "tue", traffic: 120}, {name: "wed", traffic: 124}, {name: "thurs", traffic: 455}],
    result = data.reduce((r,o) => r.traffic < o.traffic ? o : r);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reduce() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.

```js
var weekdays = [
  {name: "mon", traffic: 123},
  {name: "tue", traffic: 120}, 
  {name: "wed", traffic: 124}, 
  {name: "thu", traffic: 455},
  {name: "fri", traffic: 455},
]


var maxTrafficWeekday = weekdays.reduce(function (acc, val) {
  return val.traffic > acc.traffic ? val : acc
})

console.log(maxTrafficWeekday)
```

The above code will return the first day which has most traffic. If you want to get the last day with most traffic, you can change the algorithm:

```js
var weekdays = [
  {name: "mon", traffic: 123},
  {name: "tue", traffic: 120}, 
  {name: "wed", traffic: 124}, 
  {name: "thu", traffic: 455},
  {name: "fri", traffic: 455},
]


var maxTrafficWeekday = weekdays.reduce(function (acc, val) {
  return val.traffic >= acc.traffic ? val : acc
  // -----------------^
})

console.log(maxTrafficWeekday)
```